# How do you make a table without column names using package "gt"

Tags: r, gt

I'm new to the R package "gt" and would like to create a periodic table. I found some code online to do this, but the code generates a table with row and column names, which I don't want. I was able to get rid of the row names, but can't remove the column names. The code that needs modification is below. Any ideas?

```
  elements <- tibble(
  rowname = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "", "", ""),

  "1" = c("1 H", "3 Li", "11 Na", "19 K", "37 Rb", "55 Cs", "87 Fr", "", "", ""),
  
"2" = c("", "4 Be", "12 Mg", "20 Ca", "38 Sr", "56 Ba", "88 Ra", "", "", ""),
  
"3" = c("", "", "", "21 Sc", "39 Y", "57 La", "89 Ac", "", "", ""),
  
" " = c(rep("", times = 5), "58-71", "90-103", "", "", ""),
  
"4" = c("", "", "", "22 Ti", "40 Zr", "72 Hf", "104 Rf", "", "58 Ce", "90 Th"),
  
"5" = c("", "", "", "23 V", "41 Nb", "73 Ta", "105 Db", "", "59 Pr", "91 Pa"),
  
"6" = c("", "", "", "24 Cr", "42 Mo", "74 W", "106 Sg", "", "60 Nd", "92 U"),
  
"7" = c("", "", "", "25 Mn", "43 Tc", "75 Re", "107 Bh", "", "61 Pm", "93 Np"),
  
"8" = c("", "", "", "26 Fe", "44 Ru", "76 Os", "108 Hs", "", "62 Sm", "94 Pu"),
  
"9" = c("", "", "", "27 Co", "45 Rh", "77 Ir", "109 Mt", "", "63 Eu", "95 Am"),
  
"10" = c("", "", "", "28 Ni", "46 Pd", "78 Pt", "110 Ds", "", "64 Gd", "96 Cm"),
  
"11" = c("", "", "", "29 Cu", "47 Ag", "79 Au", "111 Rg", "", "65 Tb", "97 Bk"),
  
"12" = c("", "", "", "30 Zn", "48 Cd", "80 Hg", "112 Cn", "", "66 Dy", "98 Cf"),
  
"13" = c("", "5 B", "13 Al", "31 Ga", "49 In", "81 Ti", "113 Nh", "", "67 Ho", "99 Es"),
  
"14" = c("", "6 C", "14 Si", "32 Ge", "50 Sn", "82 Pb", "114 Fl", "", "68 Er", "100 Fm"),
  
"15" = c("", "7 N", "15 P", "33 As", "51 Sb", "83 Bi", "115 Mc", "", "69 Tm", "101 Md"),
  
"16" = c("", "8 O", "16 S", "34 Se", "52 Te", "84 Po", "116 Lv", "", "70 Yb", "102 No"),
  
"17" = c("", "9 F", "17 Cl", "35 Br", "53 I", "85 At", "117 Ts", "", "71 Lu", "103 Lr"),
  
"18" = c("2 He", "10 Ne", "18 Ar", "36 Kr", "54 Xe", "86 Rn", "118 Og", "", "", "")
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `column_labels.hidden = TRUE`

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
elements %>% 
  select(-rowname) %>%
  gt() %>% 
  tab_options(column_labels.hidden = TRUE)
```

-output

[image]